# Why is this question off topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions, scope

I don't know why the following question is off topic:

> https://superuser.com/q/456716/109333

I thought a system administrator was a super user. Are there any Stack Exchange sites I can migrate this question to?

Comment: Update: I was told by moderators that you got a good answer already, so no real point in migration. Feel free to post any other related or more detailed questions on [SF], though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question does not relate to any actual computer hardware or software issue, and it's asking about best practices that are common for system administrators.

There are two issues with this:

- Asking for best practices is often considered not constructive (although I think your question has merit)
- We make a distinction between questions for home users (i.e. what Super User is about) and professional system administrators. This is where [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) comes into play.

I've asked the Server Fault moderators if they would like your question. If they do, I will migrate the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question, and primarily cause it was too complex to answer as a comment. This is an edge case really. Its about how to code an application (so somewhat SOish), but involves system administration (so somewhat SFish).

In the end though it was about best practices - and the wider philosophy of how to code a system, and how it needs to be used. Its just not something that would fit neatly into an answer - I know a little of this from db design classes, Forensic Data Analysis Classes and from the awesome "[The Practice of Network and System Administration](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=O3V_XuudXmYC&dq=limoncelli&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fv3iT56HCKzo2gXBls2tCw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAQ)" .

We're talking about the knowledge from half of my university modules, and there may be other ways to do it. Its just not a question that fits well anywhere.

Comment: Yes.My fault is I assumed that the experienced admins in the SU site would answer with the help of their experience.I just wanted to know how it happens rather than how to implement.Simply the "user story(user case) of handing over the admins rights" :)

Answer (score 0):

Stackexchange sites are about creating objective knowledge bases. "How do I do this?" or "why does thuis happen?" or "what is this?" are all on-topic, provided "this" is falls within the site's subject area. "What's the best way to do this" is off-topic, because the answer is usually a matter of opinion.